# What about dairy pasteurisation might have made the issue so important to Lord Rothschild?

Tags: political-history, england, united-kingdom

It’s [known](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/74150/has-it-been-common-for-lords-to-only-address-the-house-twice-in-their-entire-car) that in 50+ years of Lordship, Lord Rothschild only addressed the house twice:

- Once was about the Zionist question
- The other was about instituting compulsory pasteurisation of dairy

It’s very common for Jewish people (among others) to feel very strongly about the question/establishment of a Jewish homeland, and the existence of a Jewish “Ulster” amidst a (geologically oil-rich) “sea of Arabism” further is of naturally great foreign policy significance to the English (and other Western powers’) ruling class(es).

Since dairy pasteurisation has been mandated widely throughout the western world, strong feelings have developed among actual and would-be consumers of raw dairy lamenting the drive for continued or further restrictions on its distribution/sale, making raw dairy a contentious issue among those who hold faith in modern technology and those who are more skeptics of it. Given that the British royal family including the late Queen Elizabeth placed great personal importance on consuming regularly raw dairy into her very advanced age and in going out of her way to ensure that her grandchildren could continue to have it when they went off to boarding school, along with the well scientifically understood damage wrought by pasteurisation to dairy’s nutritional value, it is perhaps somewhat understandable for the more conspiratorially-inclined to draw inferences as to some more nefarious motivation for such a strong drive by the political class to maintain bans and restrictions on the more widely accessible distribution of raw dairy to common people given its numerous scientifically proven health benefits.

While raw dairy is on the other hand now often argued to carry greater risks of food borne pathogens, the restrictive legal bans on its distribution seems in depriving consumers of the liberty to pick their preferred poisons to be inconsistent with the approaches taken on comparative issues: while many feel (usually much more intense) aversions to (even the thought of others indulging in) the consumption of raw meat, nobody suggests that its sale should be banned, and consumers remain, throughout the world, free to choose whether to buy pre-cooked or (in fact, more commonly) raw meat products. But not with dairy.

These discrepancies no doubt leave people wondering as to the true explanation for the apparently high political will somewhere along the line to keep raw dairy’s availability tightly restricted. The fact that Lord Rothschild himself is a public political figure who is on record apparently making a high personal political priority of this issue, being of a family about whom much conspiratorial speculation of various degrees of baselessness is regularly made, gives an easy piece of easily-corroborateable supporting data to point to, and makes for some especially sensational speculative explanations.

Yet, to  jump straight from:

- an empirically observed high political will (as exemplified by a high profile political figure’s publicly verifiable personal oratory record) to keep something restricted, which
- (among many other things not subject to such political  controversy) does have some observed health benefits (including on reproductive fertility)

…to a determined antinatalist conspiracy to “reduce the population” or even “kill off humanity” does seem quite the leap, but rejecting this rather farther fetched speculative explanation does leave the gap remaining wanting for others more credible.

So, of all the issues that Lord Rothschild could have chosen to speak about in addition to the Zionist question, what about this seemingly banal issue of food safety regulations may have made it so sufficiently important to him to warrant being the other one of only two that he ever saw fit to rise and speak on?

Comment: The answer to your previous question strongly hints at the reason, no?

Comment: Very possibly, though I haven’t fully read it yet. Nonetheless I still felt that it merited a distinct question to be fully addressed in proper detail.

Comment: Ok having read the other answer I can confirm that I find it to be rather lacking in satisfactory insights.

Comment: https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/lords/1946/apr/10/pasteurization-of-milk

Comment: The Rothschild family have had a long association with milk quality standards; https://api.pageplace.de/preview/DT0400.9781351931045_A30906832/preview-9781351931045_A30906832.pdf

Comment: "*In parallel with his scientific work, Victor continued to work for the public service. He had a personal interest in farming and in 1948, he accepted appointment as Chairman of the Agricultural Research Council (AFRC).* - https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsbm.1994.0021

Answer (score 4):

Lord Rothschild's [speech to his peers](https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/lords/1946/apr/10/pasteurization-of-milk#S5LV0140P0_19460410_HOL_10) is fully in line with his studies and academic work (zoology, fertilization, germs) and also his personal and family interests (like farming).

> At Trinity College, Cambridge, Rothschild read physiology, French, and English, and was considered impressive enough an undergraduate to be spared the rigours of sitting the Natural Sciences Tripos, thus allowing him to embark immediately on a **career in scientific research**.
>
> After the War, Victor combined his academic interests with work for industry, joining the zoology department at Cambridge University. For his work on fertilization, he gained a DSc in 1950. **He served as Chairman of the Agricultural Research Council from 1948 to 1958.** [The Rothschild archive](https://family.rothschildarchive.org/people/124-nathaniel-mayer-victor-rothschild-1910-1990)

From [A Report On The Milk Supply Of Large Towns: Its Defects And Their Remedy](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20276135), we can see some that [Henri de Rothschild](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_de_Rothschild) shared (or influenced) some scientific points of view with his cousin [Victor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Rothschild,_3rd_Baron_Rothschild):

> Dr. Henri de Rothschild has recently published an abstract of the report of a mission with which ne was charged by the French Minister of Agriculture last summer to study the conditions under which the miIk trade is carried on in Denmark. **The interest which M. de Rothschild has taken in the question of the supply of milk for infants is well known**, and at the polyclinic which he established seven years ago and which is now carried on in a special building attached to the Hopital Rothschild in Paris, not only is ordinary treatment
> given to infants, but **sterilized milk is issued for their use free or at a low price and they are regularly weighed so that the effects may be register**.

[Le lait. I Les théories pasteuriennes appliquées à l'industrie laitière. II Pasteurisation et stérilisation. III Principales méthodes d'analyse. IV Fraudes et falsifications](https://family.rothschildarchive.org/bibliography/19487-le-lait-i-les-theories-pasteuriennes-appliquees-a-l-industrie-laitiere-ii-pasteurisation-et-sterilisation-iii-principales-methodes-d-analyse-iv-fraudes-et-falsifications) is an academic publication regarding the [Louis Pasteur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Pasteur) work about [Pasteurization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteurization).

The Rothschild's estate has had many castles and farms in England and France, like the [1.700 acre estate](https://family.rothschildarchive.org/estates/77-rushbrooke-hall), near Bury St Edmunds, that has been in the Rothschild family since 1938. For centuries, they grew horses, cows, produce(d) milk, apples, [cheese](https://edmondderothschildheritage.com/en/nature/), wines [1](https://edmondderothschildheritage.com/en/wines/) [2](https://www.bpdr.com/) and so on... There are great probabilities that his interest addressing the Lords were driven by his family and personal background **and** family and personal knowledge.

Some [conspiracy theorists](https://br.ifunny.co/picture/no-435623247-consider-for-a-moment-that-nathaniel-rothschild-sat-GLBZqQjgA) may argue that it was for money or killing people, but I won't argue about that here (or elsewhere...).